# por qué me lanza una excepción al agregar el siguiente bolque de codigo?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un código en php que me anda perfecto sin este bloque, pero al agregarlo me lanza: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file", a que se debe?, de antemano gracias

```
 <tbody>
    <?php
        $query="SELECT * FROM formulario";
         $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){?>
        <tr>
       <td>
      <?php echo $row['title'];?>
     </td>
    </tr>
   <?php}?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: error de sintaxis, en esta línea `echo $row['title']` te hace falta el punto y coma

Comment: capo, gracias, pero a pesar de que le añado el punto y coma, sigue con el mismo error :(

Comment: en que línea te marca el error el mensaje que aparece?

Comment: Separa con espacio las etiquetas de cierre y apertura de PHP con las llaves u otro tipo de código , `<?php } ?>` , esta falta de ese espacio, a menudo causa ese error.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 45. Mi codigo es de 44 lineas

Comment: capo, Dev, Joel. Muchas gracias, eso era